# Sync Enabled Feature Service at ArcGIS for Server Version 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, feature-service

Is sync enabled Feature Services available for ArcGIS server at version 10.1?  If not at what version was this introduced.  I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer on the web.

Answer (score 1):

A little more digging and I found the answer.  Sync enabled feature services started at Server version 10.2.1.

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/windows/prepare-data-for-offline-use.htm